# Why can't I send a string message through my program?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently I am trying to build a simple node where I send a `string` using the `std_msgs::String.h` message class. What I do understand is, why I get these particular errors.

##Code ##

**Includes:**

```
// NORMAL INCLUDES 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// ROS INCLUDES 
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
```

**Declaration:**

```
ros::Publisher command;
command = node.advertise<std_msgs::String>("/command", 1);
```

**While loop:**

```
while (ros::ok()) { 

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Type your Command Below:" << std::endl << std::endl; 
    getline(std::cin, input);

    command.publish(input); 

}
```

##Errors ##

```
In file included from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/serialization.h:37:0,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/publisher.h:34,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/sharan/catkin_ws/src/zlab_drone/src/demo_usr_input.cpp:9:
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/message_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum<M>::value(const M&) [with M = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/message_traits.h:255:102:   required from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::md5sum(const M&) [with M = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7:   required from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/home/sharan/catkin_ws/src/zlab_drone/src/demo_usr_input.cpp:45:30:   required from here
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/message_traits.h:126:34: error: ‘const class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ has no member named ‘__getMD5Sum’
     return m.__getMD5Sum().c_str();
                                  ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/message_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::DataType<M>::value(const M&) [with M = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/message_traits.h:264:104:   required from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::datatype(const M&) [with M = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7:   required from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/home/sharan/catkin_ws/src/zlab_drone/src/demo_usr_input.cpp:45:30:   required from here
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/message_traits.h:143:36: error: ‘const class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ has no member named ‘__getDataType’
     return m.__getDataType().c_str();
                                    ^
```

### String,msg ## [Link is here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html)

```
string data
```

Since they are the same type looking at `String.h`, I do not understand why I am getting this error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256448/why-can%27t-i-send-a-string-message-through-my-program?/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should send an std_msgs/String not an std::string.

```
std_msgs::String msg;
msg.data = input;
command.publish(msg);
```

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-03-08**:
That's it! Thanks!